# Suppose a group $G$ has subgroups of order $25$ and $35,$ and $|G|\leq 340.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could anyone advise on how to find the order of $G ?$ By Lagrange theorem, $25$ and $35$ divides $|G|$, so $|G|\geq 875? $

Comment: You may employ the Sylow theorems?

Comment: What'd we want Sylow theorems here for?

Answer (score 8):

The LCM of 25 and 35 is 175, and the next highest multiple is 350.
Since $|G|$ is divisible by both 25 and 35, we must have $|G|= 175$.